# How to Make jQuery Cycle Through Clicks Every Few Seconds?

Tags: jquery, slider, each

I have created a very basic image slider that changes images when a div is clicked (code below). I would like to set it to auto-progress every 5 seconds. Looking at other posts, it seems like I could do something with `window.setInterval(event, 5000);` and then have the event fire a click on the next div every 5 seconds. I am having some trouble setting up this each function though. My code is below, I would appreciate any help:

HTML:

```
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-images">
      <img class="1" src="assets/slider-1.jpg" width="613" height="344">
      <img class="2" src="assets/slider-2.jpg" width="613" height="344">
      <img class="3" src="assets/slider-3.jpg" width="613" height="344">
      <img class="4" src="assets/slider-4.jpg" width="613" height="344">
      <img class="5" src="assets/slider-5.jpg" width="613" height="344">
      <img class="6" src="assets/slider-6.jpg" width="613" height="344">
    </div>

<div id="slider-nav">
  <div class="description" id="1">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description" id="2">
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description" id="3">
    <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description" id="4">
    <h1>Heading 4</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description" id="5">
    <h1>Heading 5</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="description" id="6">
    <h1>Heading 6</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  //homepage slider
  $('#slider-nav div:first').addClass('current');
  $('#slider-images img').hide();
  $('#slider-images img:first').addClass('current').show();

  $('#slider-nav div').click(function(){
    var id        = $(this).attr('id');
    var sliderImg = "#slider-images img";
    $(sliderImg).removeClass('current');
    $(sliderImg).fadeOut('slow');
    $(sliderImg + "." + id).fadeIn('slow');

    $("#slider-nav div").removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    var $next = $('#slider-nav div.current').next();
    if ($next.length==0) $next = $('#slider-nav div:first')
    $next.trigger('click')
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working, but I think it is really close. I think their may be something wrong with the syntax. Anyone more skilled them I am able to spot what's wrong?

Comment: What does it do when you run this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything. Looking at it thought it seems to make sense. Is the syntax on the if clause correct?

Comment: this worked for me when i pasted your code and my code into jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/e5JKg/). what wasnt working?

Comment: yes, that syntax is correct. if you only are going to run one line after an `if` clause, you dont need the `{}`

Comment: Okay, I'm an idiot, I had changed something slightly in my code between posting and now and forgot about it. When reverted back it works great! Thanks so much for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be better off using a scroller library such as jQuery Cycle: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It's easy to implement, has a small footprint, lots of examples, and you would just need to modify your HTML a little bit to implement it. It solves your problem too.

If you really want your solution, how about this (modified @Jeff's)

```
var $next;
setInterval(function()
{
    if ($next == undefined || $next.next().length == 0) { 
        $('#slider-nav div:first'); 
    } else {
        $next = $next.next();
}
$next.trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically make the click function an actual named function, then call that every 5 seconds like so:

```
$('#slider-nav div').click(myClickHandler());
//Might have to do "myClickHandler()" - I cannot test this right now

function myClickHandler()
{
    var id        = $('#slider-nav div').attr('id');
    var sliderImg = "#slider-images img";
    $(sliderImg).removeClass('current');
    $(sliderImg).fadeOut('slow');
    $(sliderImg + "." + id).fadeIn('slow');

    $("#slider-nav div").removeClass('current');
    $('#slider-nav div').addClass('current');
    return false;
}

window.setInterval("myClickHandler()", 5000);
```

Comment: The problem with this though is that it fires a click on every div every 5 seconds. I need to cycle through the divs so #1 is clicked and then 5 seconds later #2 is clicked. Does that make sense?